# Understanding Index w/ Cast

Tags: postgresql, index

Given:

```
postgres=# \d b
                Table "public.b"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | uuid |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "b_a_idx" btree (a)

postgres=# \d c
                Table "public.c"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | text |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "c_a_idx" btree (a)

postgres=# explain b;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "b"
LINE 1: explain b;
                ^
postgres=# analyze b; 
ANALYZE
postgres=# analyze c;
ANALYZE
```

Why does the following quering not use `b.a`'s index?

```
postgres=# explain (select * from b join c on (b.a :: text) = c.a);
                                   QUERY PLAN                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=129.05..455.25 rows=12580 width=48)
   Merge Cond: (c.a = ((b.a)::text))
   ->  Index Only Scan using c_a_idx on c  (cost=0.15..64.55 rows=1360 width=32)
   ->  Sort  (cost=128.89..133.52 rows=1850 width=16)
         Sort Key: ((b.a)::text)
         ->  Seq Scan on b  (cost=0.00..28.50 rows=1850 width=16)
(6 rows)
```

Comment: How many records in each table?

Comment: As a side note: it's not necessary to enclose the actual query in parentheses when using `explain` or `explain (analyze)`

Comment: @Vérace there are 0 rows in each table

Comment: Why would you expect the optimiser to choose an index if there are no records? Even if you follow @a_horse_with_no_name 's strategy - the index will be ignored anyway - the optimiser will say something like "no records - no need to use an index - it's faster to just scan the whole table" - it will say the same for a small (not sure where the tipping point is!) number of records. If you want to test this sort of thing, you should use the generate_series function to produce tables with large amounts of data!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Why does the following query not use b.a's index?*

Because the index only stores the UUID value of `a`, not the result of the expression `a::text`

To make the index eligible for use, you would need to cast the other column to the data type stored in the index, e.g.

```
select * 
from b 
   join c on b.a = c.a::uuid;
```

Note that this doesn't *guarantee* that the index is used, it just makes it *possible*.

But as the query retrieves all rows from both tables, it's highly unlikely that the index is used anyway.